# Can the Android SDK work with JDK 1.8?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, java-8

I have a java project compiled with java 1.8 working on eclipse, now i want to change that code android project, but after setting complier as jdk 1.8 my error of java are not removing, that means that the compiler not working with 1.8 , please suggest how can i compile my android code with jdk 1.8.

Comment: _my error of java are not removing_ what are those errors?

Comment: 1.8 JDK works just fine with Android SDK. There is nothing to do with it, it works *from the box*. Another thing is that Android does not support all Java 8 features (like lambda). So not all Java 8 code will compile for Android.

Comment: show your error

Comment: 1. Integer.BYTES (BYTES cannot be resolved or is not a field)   2. JSONObject.stringToValue(str); (The method stringToValue(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject)

Comment: i am getting theses type of errors.

Comment: Also , while changing java compiler to 1.8 , i was getting error in cmd : Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.8' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.